# How to disable "pre-charge" while generating a periodical signal using a Keithley2635B sourcemeter?

Tags: python, signal-processing

Good day,

**Context:**

I am trying to source custom waveforms using a Keithley 2635B sourcemeter. Using the trigger attribute `listv` and the timer attribute `delaylist` it is easy to do but an unexpected behavior appears.

As you can see on the attached picture, I am sourcing a very simple square signal (two points `+A` and `–A` with the same delay) and repeat it a number of times using `smua.trigger.arm.count = <Periods>`. Notice how the signal plateaus at the start of each new period? It only happens when crossing 0, if I add an offset so that the signal keeps the same sign there is no issue. This plateau has a very consistent duration of 125 µs regardless of which frequency I try to source. Its impact is not negligible anymore at high frequencies.

[image]

Below is the portion of the code that matters. Code that is upstream only processes the various parameters given by the user (frequency, amplitude, offset, etc) to create the appropriate`listv` and `delaylist`. Lua commands sent to the Keithley are wrapped with the `WRITE()` function so that the rest of the program can be written in Python.

```
# Source V
K.WRITE("smua.source.func = smua.OUTPUT_DCVOLTS")

# Configure actions to start immediately.
K.WRITE("smua.trigger.arm.stimulus = 0") 
K.WRITE("smua.trigger.source.stimulus = 0") 
K.WRITE("smua.trigger.endpulse.stimulus = 0")  

# Configure the source action.
K.WRITE("smua.trigger.source.action = smua.ENABLE")              
K.WRITE("smua.trigger.endpulse.action = smua.SOURCE_HOLD")       
K.WRITE("smua.trigger.source.listv(%s)" %SourceArray)
K.WRITE("smua.trigger.arm.count = %d" %Periods)        
K.WRITE("smua.trigger.count = %d" %PointsPerPeriod)

# Delay between outputs
K.WRITE("trigger.timer[1].reset()")
K.WRITE("trigger.timer[1].delaylist = {}".format(DelayArray))
K.WRITE("trigger.timer[1].stimulus = smua.trigger.SOURCE_COMPLETE_EVENT_ID")
K.WRITE("smua.trigger.measure.stimulus = trigger.timer[1].EVENT_ID")

# Start the trigger to generate the AC signal then turn off the output when done.
K.WRITE("smua.source.output = 1")
K.WRITE("smua.trigger.initiate()")
K.WRITE(“waitcomplete()”)
K.WRITE("smua.source.output = 0")
```

**Question:**

The sourcemeter documentation indicates that

> in cases where the first sweep point is a nonzero value, it may be
>   necessary to pre-charge the circuit so that the sweep will return a
>   stable value for the first measured point without penalizing remaining
>   points in the sweep.

so I assume the plateau I witness is pre-charge at the beginning of every repetition. Is there a way to disable it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you need `smua.trigger.endsweep.action = smua.SOURCE_HOLD`.

Comment: This is amazing, it got rid of the plateaus, thank a lot! For some reason I did not notice that `smua.trigger.endsweep` and `smua.trigger.endpulse` were distinct.

Comment: Actually, it gets rid of the zeros **between repetitions** but now I witness those when my signal crosses zero instead. Surprisingly it does not happen for square signals.